# Como puedo mostrar un mensaje en css cuando el input en este caso email es :invalid?

Tags: html, css, frontend

tengo 2 input tipo email, con su respectivo botón de submit al que quiero agregarle respectivamente su mensaje de alerta pero a lo que he aprendido trato de hacerlo así[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ahora este código parece que solo funciona para los dos pero el estilo de cada uno es diferente ya que la posición son diferentes como podría darle un pósicionamiento diferente a cada uno o si hay mejores opciones para colocar un mensaje de alerta en el momento de colocar un correo en el input, gracias.

Comment: Hola @Horacio Chaverri Ortega, te recomiendo que quites la imagen de la pregunta y coloques el código en texto, de lo contrario no tardarán en "lloverte" votos negativos, he incluso puede que cierren tu pregunta, te podrías hacer una pasada por https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour, para saber como manejarte en este sitio.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Lo que estás haciendo es una validación al `form` en general por eso muestra un solo mensaje. El form es `invalid` si al menos un elemento hijo es invalid.

Lo que tú quieres es mostrar un mensaje por `input`, para esto debes crear un elemento adicional (un hermano del input) para en él mostrar el mensaje, algo como esto:

*(yo usaré un `span`)*

```css
input:invalid{
  border: 1px solid red;
}


input[type=email]:invalid + span:after{
  content:"Please check yout email";
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<form>

 <div>
    <input type="email"  required>
    <span></span>
 </div>
 
  <div>
    <input type="email"  required>
    <span></span>
 </div>
 
<form>
```

También podrías querer un mensaje diferente cada input, en este caso colocamos el mensaje dentro del span y lo mostramos o ocultamos según sea el caso

```css
input:invalid{
  border: 1px solid red;
}

input + span{
  color:red;
}
input[type=email]:valid + span{
  visibility:collapse
}
input[type=email]:invalid + span{
  visibility:visible
}
```

```html
<form>

 <div>
    <input type="email"  required>
    <span>Please check yout email 1111</span>
 </div>
 
  <div>
    <input type="email"  required>
    <span>Please check yout email 2222</span>
 </div>
 
<form>
```

Esto y poco mas es posible hacer solo con CSS, lamentablemente la especificación siempre va 20 años atrasada. Por ejemplo, si deseas que inicialmente no muestre los mensajes ni el borde rojo o si quieres distintos tipos de mensajes a cada input (un mensaje cuando falla requerido, otro distinto cuando falla por su largo, etc) necesitas si o si Javascript

Answer (score 0):

Como menciona Yussef, necesitas de un elemento que funcione como contenedor para el mensaje. Lo que te comparto es parecido sólo que usé la propiedad `visivility`.

Primero creamos la etiqueta `<span>` y añadimos la clase `err`

En el `CSS` ocultamos la clase `err` con `hidden`

Luego indicamos que cuando el `input` email sea invalido pase al siguiente elemento que indica la condición, que en este caso es la clase `err`

Aqui ya añadimos las propiedades necesarias, y una de las importantes de hacer visible nuestra clase con `visible`

```css
input[type=email]:invalid{
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border: 1 solid red;
    outline: 0;
}
.err{
    visibility: hidden;
}
input[type=email]:invalid + .err::before{
    content: 'Please check your email';
    visibility: visible;
    color: red;
    font-size: 15px;
}
input[type=submit]{
    display: block;
    margin: 10px 0px;
}
```

```html
<form>
     <input type="email">
     <span class="err"></span>
     <input type="submit">

     <input type="email">
     <span class="err"></span>
     <input type="submit">
</form>
```